# Weighted accuracy, sensitivity and specificity

Tags: machine-learning, python, accuracy, confusion-matrix, weighted-data

I have a confusion matrix
TN= 27 FP=20
FN =11 TP=6

I want to calculate the weighted average for accuracy, sensitivity and specificity. I know the equation but unsure how to do the weighted averages.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration that:
[image]

Weighted Average Precision, Recall, f1score, specificity, could be calculated using:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have some codes, you can check it in, and the complete references:

[0] https://github.com/sisifo3/Metrics_Imbalanced_learn

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pYZh.png) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ySAKEzZTZA